# Single value in ionic http post param

Tags: ionic-framework

Hi I'm new to ionic/angular and I'm reading someone else code and came across the function below in the `Service`

```
 makePostRequest(100)
 
 public makePostRequest(param) {
   return this.http.post('/sample/api', param);
 }
```

Does this mean param is sent as json body or just a value, online documentation just shows json body as the argument not a single value. Can someone help me with this

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post body is sent as serialized parameters as explained [here](https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request).

In the example you have provided, they are calling the `makePostRequest()` function and providing an argument of `100`. When the `makePostRequest()` function runs, it takes that value from the argument and sets it as a parameter which is then used to populate the body in the POST request.

You can still send single values as you would multiple values with something similar to this:

```
sendData() {
   const data = {
      number: 100
   };
   return this.http.post('myurl.com', data);
}
```

Or for multiple:

```
sendData() {
   const data = {
      number: 100,
      fruit: 'banana'
   };
   return this.http.post('myurl.com', data);
}
```

You can of course pass multiple arguments if you have parameters set up to accept them:

```
sendData(body: { score: number, fruit: string }) {
   return this.http.post('myurl.com', body);
}
```